# Call Tree Data Missing From Profiling Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, profiler

I am attempting to use the Visual Studio Performance Profiler to profile a process I have running.  I am using the "Sampling" collection type, and am attaching to the process after it has already started.  When I finish profiling and attempt to load the report, it displays the message "No Call Tree Data Is Available" above the CPU usage graph.

In addition, the following error is generated:

> DA0002: It appears that the file was collected without properly
>   setting the environment variables with VSPerfCLREnv.cmd. Symbols for
>   managed binaries may not resolve.

The only information I can find on this error is around running the profiler from the command line, not from Visual Studio.

My best guess is that this may be a 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue, as I just recently received an upgraded computer with the 64-bit of Windows 7.  Everything worked fine on my previous machine which had the 32-bit version of Windows 7.